# Back button navigation without reload the previous page in vue js

Tags: vue.js

i have created 3 pages, first page is navigating to second page and second page is navigating to 3rd page, how ever when i click back button it is navigating to previous page but its not giving last history intead of its reloading the page,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is normal as the previous component's instance is destroyed. You can `console.log` in each [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) to see which hooks are called when a route is entered and exited.

To prevent this behaviour and cache your route's component you can wrap the `<router-view>` inside [`<keep-alive>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive)

```
<keep-alive>
    <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

You can even pass `include` and `exclude` props on `<keep-alive>` to manage which component to or not be cached